# biblatex package suddenly missing

Tags: biblatex, packages, natbib, missing

I am on a Windows machine using:

Editor: TexStudio 3.1.1

Compiler: pdflatex

Bibliography tool: biber

Bibliography manager: natbib

Today, I was editing my thesis document (just the text at the time, no figures, no tables, no new packages, etc.) and I went to compile & view in order to check my changes in the PDF viewer and suddenly I started getting a `"Missing 'biblatex' package" error`. I have no idea what could have caused this and the best I can come up with is that it has to do with natbib. I don't really want to change my paper to use a different package and I also am just curious about how this happened.
Normally, I never get to the stage where I actually post a question because I find the problem while trying to get to a minimum reproducible example, but not this time. The error still occurs with the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\title{Simple Example}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum...

    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

In fact, it's the only message in my log. No warnings or anything else. The log tells me that the error is in the .bbl file, but I'm pretty sure that is just the branch statement that checks for the presence of the biblatex package not the cause of the error.

I did not leave my computer or even close TexStudio between the last time it worked fine and when I started getting this error.

To troubleshoot: I have checked that biblatex is installed, I have updated MikTex, I have updated my package database through MikTek console (both as user and admin), I have updated TexStudio, I have checked that biblatex.cwl is checked in TexStudio config (not that it should matter for this), I have tried using a different editor (TexMaker), and I have tried walking back my changes since the last time it worked.

When I transfer everything to Overleaf it runs fine and, oddly, switching the bib manager from natbib to biblatex seems to work but it messes up my formatting. So, I suspect that there is something that my computer suddenly doesn't like about natbib but I cannot imagine what it might be at this point or why it happened so suddenly.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:
I also deleted the .bbl file and the .aux file between each troubleshooting step.

EDIT 2:
Here is the logfile as requested in the comments.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.6) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.6.9)  9 JUN 2021 02:58
entering extended mode
**./thesis.tex
(thesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2021-06-01> (ClemsonThesis.cls
Document Class: ClemsonThesis 2007/05/31 Version 1.0 by Andrew R. Dalton, Schoo
l of Computing
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\book.cls
Document Class: book 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count182
\c@chapter=\count183
\c@section=\count184
\c@subsection=\count185
\c@subsubsection=\count186
\c@paragraph=\count187
\c@subparagraph=\count188
\c@figure=\count189
\c@table=\count190
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hypertext links for LaTeX

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcm
ds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr
.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys
.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefi
nekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape
.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmac
ro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.s
ty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen139
\Hy@linkcounter=\count191
\Hy@pagecounter=\count192

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref-lan
gpatches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: patches for babel la
nguages
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.s
ty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count193

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `plainpages' set `false' on input line 4073.
Package hyperref Info: Option `pdfpagelabels' set `true' on input line 4073.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4200.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4207.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4212.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4445.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count194

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4804.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen140

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintca
lc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count195
\Field@Width=\dimen141
\Fld@charsize=\dimen142
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6081.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6084.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6091.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6096.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6101.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6146.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6150.

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count196
\c@Item=\count197
\c@Hfootnote=\count198
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.st
y
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count199
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count266

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunf
ilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniqu
ecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip49
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count267
\Gm@cntv=\count268
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count269
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen143
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen144
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen145
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen146
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen147
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen148
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen149
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen150
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg
))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/appendix\appendix.sty
Package: appendix 2020/02/08 v1.2c extra appendix facilities
\c@@pps=\count270
\c@@ppsavesec=\count271
\c@@ppsaveapp=\count272
) (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tocloft\tocloft.sty
Package: tocloft 2017/08/31 v2.3i parameterised ToC, etc., typesetting
Package tocloft Info: The document has chapter divisions on input line 51.
\cftparskip=\skip50
\cftbeforetoctitleskip=\skip51
\cftaftertoctitleskip=\skip52
\cftbeforepartskip=\skip53
\cftpartnumwidth=\skip54
\cftpartindent=\skip55
\cftbeforechapskip=\skip56
\cftchapindent=\skip57
\cftchapnumwidth=\skip58
\cftbeforesecskip=\skip59
\cftsecindent=\skip60
\cftsecnumwidth=\skip61
\cftbeforesubsecskip=\skip62
\cftsubsecindent=\skip63
\cftsubsecnumwidth=\skip64
\cftbeforesubsubsecskip=\skip65
\cftsubsubsecindent=\skip66
\cftsubsubsecnumwidth=\skip67
\cftbeforeparaskip=\skip68
\cftparaindent=\skip69
\cftparanumwidth=\skip70
\cftbeforesubparaskip=\skip71
\cftsubparaindent=\skip72
\cftsubparanumwidth=\skip73
\cftbeforeloftitleskip=\skip74
\cftafterloftitleskip=\skip75
\cftbeforefigskip=\skip76
\cftfigindent=\skip77
\cftfignumwidth=\skip78
\c@lofdepth=\count273
\c@lotdepth=\count274
\cftbeforelottitleskip=\skip79
\cftafterlottitleskip=\skip80
\cftbeforetabskip=\skip81
\cfttabindent=\skip82
\cfttabnumwidth=\skip83
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\indentfirst.sty
Package: indentfirst 1995/11/23 v1.03 Indent first paragraph (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2021/01/28 v4.0.1 Extensive control of page headers and foote
rs
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip84
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip85
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip86
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip87
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip88
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip89
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip90
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip91
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip92
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/12/05 v1.2c Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics
.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.d
ef
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen151
\Gin@req@width=\dimen152
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/setspace\setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/adjustbox\adjustbox.s
ty
Package: adjustbox 2020/08/19 v1.3 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.te
x
\XKV@toks=\toks18
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks19
)
\XKV@depth=\count275
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/adjustbox\adjcalc.sty
Package: adjcalc 2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back
-ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/adjustbox\trimclip.st
y
Package: trimclip 2020/08/19 v1.2 Trim and clip general TeX material

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/collectbox\collectbox
.sty
Package: collectbox 2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
\collectedbox=\box50
)
\tc@llx=\dimen153
\tc@lly=\dimen154
\tc@urx=\dimen155
\tc@ury=\dimen156
Package trimclip Info: Using driver 'tc-pdftex.def'.

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/adjustbox\tc-pdftex.d
ef
File: tc-pdftex.def 2019/01/04 v2.2 Clipping driver for pdftex
))
\adjbox@Width=\dimen157
\adjbox@Height=\dimen158
\adjbox@Depth=\dimen159
\adjbox@Totalheight=\dimen160
\adjbox@pwidth=\dimen161
\adjbox@pheight=\dimen162
\adjbox@pdepth=\dimen163
\adjbox@ptotalheight=\dimen164

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ifoddpage\ifoddpage.s
ty
Package: ifoddpage 2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
\c@checkoddpage=\count276
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/varwidth\varwidth.sty
Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
\@vwid@box=\box51
\sift@deathcycles=\count277
\@vwid@loff=\dimen165
\@vwid@roff=\dimen166
))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/04/20 v2.17j AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip93

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks20
\ex@=\dimen167
))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen168
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count278
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count279
\leftroot@=\count280
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count281
\DOTSCASE@=\count282
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box52
\strutbox@=\box53
\big@size=\dimen169
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count283
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count284
\dotsspace@=\muskip17
\c@parentequation=\count285
\dspbrk@lvl=\count286
\tag@help=\toks21
\row@=\count287
\column@=\count288
\maxfields@=\count289
\andhelp@=\toks22
\eqnshift@=\dimen170
\alignsep@=\dimen171
\tagshift@=\dimen172
\tagwidth@=\dimen173
\totwidth@=\dimen174
\lineht@=\dimen175
\@envbody=\toks23
\multlinegap=\skip94
\multlinetaggap=\skip95
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks24
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/booktabs\booktabs.sty
Package: booktabs 2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen176
\lightrulewidth=\dimen177
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen178
\belowrulesep=\dimen179
\belowbottomsep=\dimen180
\aboverulesep=\dimen181
\abovetopsep=\dimen182
\cmidrulesep=\dimen183
\cmidrulekern=\dimen184
\defaultaddspace=\dimen185
\@cmidla=\count290
\@cmidlb=\count291
\@aboverulesep=\dimen186
\@belowrulesep=\dimen187
\@thisruleclass=\count292
\@lastruleclass=\count293
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen188
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\euscript.sty
Package: euscript 2009/06/22 v3.00 Euler Script fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\EuScript' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/eus/m/n --> U/eus/b/n on input line 33.
) (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/float\float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count294
\float@exts=\toks25
\float@box=\box54
\@float@everytoks=\toks26
\@floatcapt=\box55
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\lscape.sty
Package: lscape 2020/05/28 v3.02 Landscape Pages (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/multirow\multirow.sty
Package: multirow 2021/03/15 v2.8 Span multiple rows of a table
\multirow@colwidth=\skip96
\multirow@cntb=\count295
\multirow@dima=\skip97
\bigstrutjot=\dimen189
) (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip98
\bibsep=\skip99
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count296
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ragged2e\ragged2e.sty
Package: ragged2e 2021/02/05 v3.0 ragged2e Package
\CenteringLeftskip=\skip100
\RaggedLeftLeftskip=\skip101
\RaggedRightLeftskip=\skip102
\CenteringRightskip=\skip103
\RaggedLeftRightskip=\skip104
\RaggedRightRightskip=\skip105
\CenteringParfillskip=\skip106
\RaggedLeftParfillskip=\skip107
\RaggedRightParfillskip=\skip108
\JustifyingParfillskip=\skip109
\CenteringParindent=\skip110
\RaggedLeftParindent=\skip111
\RaggedRightParindent=\skip112
\JustifyingParindent=\skip113
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\subcaption.st
y
Package: subcaption 2020/10/07 v1.3j Sub-captions (AR)
 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption.sty
Package: caption 2020/10/26 v3.5g Customizing captions (AR)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2020/10/21 v2.2e caption3 kernel (AR)
\captionmargin=\dimen190
\captionmargin@=\dimen191
\captionwidth=\dimen192
\caption@tempdima=\dimen193
\caption@indent=\dimen194
\caption@parindent=\dimen195
\caption@hangindent=\dimen196
Package caption Info: Standard document class detected.
)
\c@caption@flags=\count297
\c@continuedfloat=\count298
Package caption Info: float package is loaded.
Package caption Info: hyperref package is loaded.
)
\c@subfigure=\count299
\c@subtable=\count300
) (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\verbatim.sty
Package: verbatim 2020-07-07 v1.5u LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
\every@verbatim=\toks27
\verbatim@line=\toks28
\verbatim@in@stream=\read2
) (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/import\import.sty
Package: import 2020/04/01  v 6.2
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 77.

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/subfiles\subfiles.sty
Package: subfiles 2020/11/14 v2.2 Multi-file projects (package)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-p
dftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-05-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count301
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box56
) (thesis.aux)
\openout1 = `thesis.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 89.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 89.

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\color.sty
Package: color 2020/02/24 v1.2b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cf
g
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 149.
)
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 89.

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2021-04-02 v2.47 Cross-referencing by name of section

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gett
itlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count302
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 89.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 89.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 89.
 (thesis.out) (thesis.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `thesis.out'.


*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: letterpaper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(90.3375pt, 433.62001pt, 90.3375pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(90.3375pt, 614.295pt, 90.3375pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=433.62001pt
* \textheight=614.295pt
* \oddsidemargin=18.0675pt
* \evensidemargin=18.0675pt
* \topmargin=-11.99998pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=18.06749pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=25.29494pt
* \marginparwidth=69.0pt
* \marginparsep=7.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)


(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.
mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count303
\scratchdimen=\dimen197
\scratchbox=\box57
\nofMPsegments=\count304
\nofMParguments=\count305
\everyMPshowfont=\toks29
\MPscratchCnt=\count306
\MPscratchDim=\dimen198
\MPnumerator=\count307
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count308
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks30
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf
-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys
.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
 [1



{C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(abstract.tex) [2


] (thesis.toc
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 1.

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 1.

(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
))
\tf@toc=\write4
\openout4 = `thesis.toc'.


[3

] (thesis.lot)
\tf@lot=\write5
\openout5 = `thesis.lot'.

 [4

] (thesis.lof)
\tf@lof=\write6
\openout6 = `thesis.lof'.

 [5

] (thesis.bbl

! LaTeX Error: Missing 'biblatex' package.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.16   {}
         
The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.

) (thesis.aux)
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `thesis.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 5F6943F7A8C0819421DEAC2D2610376E;426.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13221 strings out of 478864
 205545 string characters out of 2847713
 513887 words of memory out of 3000000
 30905 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 406645 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 83i,5n,131p,303b,353s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
<C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/t
ype1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb><C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Mi
KTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on thesis.pdf (5 pages, 66315 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 71 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 11 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 33 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Delete the `.bbl` file and try again. (Also try the document shown in the question in a new, empty directory.) I think an error like this appears when the `.bbl` file was created for `biblatex` (e.g. because the document used `biblatex` previously) but the document no longer uses `biblatex`. If that does not help, please post the `.log` file of the document that does not compile.

Comment: If you switch from biblatex to natbib or the other way round then you should delete the bbl and then recreate it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to mention that I actually did that between every step of troubleshooting.

Comment: Mhhh, note that "Bibliography tool: biber" is wrong when you want to use `natbib`. `natbib` only works with BIbTeX, so you need to switch back from Biber to BibTeX (follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) in reverse. (Although I can't reproduce the issue when I erroneously run Biber on your document: For Biber just complains, aborts processing immediately and does not start writing a `.bbl` file, which you seem to have hanging around.)

Comment: Just to avoid confusion. The `Missing 'biblatex' package" error` is triggered by the `.bbl` file if it is loaded in a document that does not load `biblatex`. The check that is performed to trigger the error does not check if `biblatex` is installed on your system (which it most likely is), it really only checks if `biblatex` is loaded (which in the example it is not). This check is written to the `.bbl` file by Biber/BibTeX when they produce the `.bbl` file for `biblatex`. In your example there should be absolutely no reason for Biber/BibTeX to do so. ...

Comment: ... In particular when compiled in a clean directory, Biber should refuse to run at all on your document and BibTeX should run with `plain.bst` and not `biblatex.bst`.

Comment: Just a thought: Did you also delete the `.bcf` file between runs? If your editor erroneously calls Biber and a `.bcf` file is present from previous experiments/runs with `biblatex`, Biber might run and produce a `.bbl`. Delete the `.bcf` (and `.aux` and `.bbl` for good measure) and tell your editor to run BibTeX, not Biber.

Comment: The `.log` file does not come from the document you have shown (it uses a different document class and appears to be much longer), so it might be dangerous to draw conclusions from that file. For all I can see the problem is indeed a `.bbl` file written for `biblatex`. I'd like to refer you to my three comments above: Delete the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf`. Tell your editor to run BibTeX and not Biber. Then compile again.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the actual issue, but `plain` is not compatible with `natbib`'s `authoryear` option. You'll need a `natbib` style (like `plainnat`) or `natbib`-compatible style for citations to actually come out as author-year citations.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. After several hours, it has started working again and I'm not sure why. It may have been when I switched from biber to bibtex as @moewe mentioned, but I can't seem to re-break it to confirm. But I will leave it on bibtex.